# Implementing Multiplayer for SpriteKit game with Game Center

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-center, gamekit

I have a completed Sprite Kit game that is solid on it's own, However I would really like to incorporate real-time multiplayer functionality into it. The only problem is I have not been able to find any tutorials going over how to do so (raywenderlich.com has one but it is with Objective-C and my game is in Swift).

I have read through Apple's documentation, however, it really just covers the logic of what is happening and lists pieces that are used as opposed to actually showing how to implement the code.

I was wondering if someone could help me with how to actually go about implementing the code. From what I can tell through my searches it is a pretty requested topic but there aren't any tutorial on this using swift.

Comment: so convert the objective-c example to swift (http://swiftify.com/) or check on GitHub. other than that you need to show that you've made an actual effort into this versus people spending their time to give you the code